# PySpark - Aggregating by hourly intervals gives TypeError: Column is not iterable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in this format:

```
Datetime (UTC format)            group          value
2022-04-01 00:00:00+00:00          A              10
2022-04-03 00:00:00+00:00          A              12.5
2022-03-01 00:00:00+00:00          B              8
```

I want to group by each group and then sum the values for that group within each **hourly** interval.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
df = df.withColumn('formatted_time', F.to_timestamp('datetime'))
df = df.groupBy('group', F.window('formatted_time', '1 hour').alias('model_window')) \
    .sum(F.col('value')).alias('value')
```

But, running this code gives me the error: `TypeError: Column is not iterable`  in the second line. I looked for solutions online but I haven't been able to figure out the cause of this error.

Could someone tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try with agg.

```
df.groupBy(f.window('formatted_time', '1 hour').alias('model_window')) \
  .agg(f.sum(f.col('value')).alias('value'))

+------------------------------------------+-----+
|model_window                              |value|
+------------------------------------------+-----+
|{2022-04-01 00:00:00, 2022-04-01 01:00:00}|10.0 |
|{2022-04-03 00:00:00, 2022-04-03 01:00:00}|12.5 |
|{2022-03-01 00:00:00, 2022-03-01 01:00:00}|8.0  |
+------------------------------------------+-----+
```